# Any good resources on implementing Firmware OTA over BLE?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'd love to get a good overview of strategies applied to execute firmware updates over-the-air (FOTA / OTA via BLE) via Bluetooth Low Energy 4.1 and beyond.

The assumption being that the Client is an Android and / or iOS device.

Any hints and help are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Do you have a specific module/chip in mind for the peripheral device? Some vendors already provide a FOTA (Firmware Over the Air) service that is supported by their SDK or APIs on the embedded device.

Otherwise, if the vendor does not support it or you would like to implement your own, then you could follow the guidelines and model your system after theirs.

Here are some links that may help you:

- [mbed FOTA service](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/wiki/Firmware-Over-the-Air-FOTA-Updates)
- [Cypress FOTA upgrade guidelines](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/application-notes/an97060-psoc-4-ble-and-proc-ble-over-air-ota-device-firmware-upgrade)
- [ST FOTA upgrade](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/09/72/f9/6b/d7/8f/48/fd/DM00293821/files/DM00293821.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00293821.pdf)
- [Make sure your firmware file and update process are secure](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2014-I9_Insecure_Software/Firmware)